# Pause after loop in TweenJS

Tags: javascript, tween

I'm hoping that some of you have worked with tween.js (part of the create.js suite of libs).

I have a JS Fiddle to show you my issue: http://jsfiddle.net/qyp8Y/1/

I'm seeing a pause after each 8 step loop, which shouldn't be there.

Can someone have a look at it and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, lets step though some code:

```
for (i = 0; i <= 8; i++) {
    t.to({
        rotation: 45 * i
    }, 1000, Ease.elasticOut).wait(200);
}
```

Here are the values you are creating in that loop:

```
i : rotation 
0 : 0
1 : 45
2 : 90
3 : 135
4 : 180
5 : 225
6 : 270
7 : 315
8 : 360
```

Note that for your purposes 0 and 360 are the same value. This means that when the loop starts over from the beginning, it is tweening from 360 to 0 (or nowhere) for one whole second.

Your object starts at rotation 0 and you can't get rid of the tween to 360. You can, though, remove the redundant tween to 0/360 by starting with the tween to 45 (starting i at 1)

That change results in this (note: I also changed the ease so I could see it better):

```
for (i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
    t.to({
        rotation: 45 * i
    }, 1000, Ease.quadInOut).wait(200);
}
```

Of course, the next problem to solve is how to make the gear rotate but not lose the correct lighting/shadow direction as it does. I'll leave that to you.

Update: I found this via the github issue you filed.

Comment: Epic, thanks a lot! The gear is the simplest I could find in google's cache, my real gears will probably be generated in JS using code I'm stealing from the gears.py extension in Inkscape. :) I just figured out how to place gears next to each other at random angles with nicely interlocking teeth. (But using only one size gear for now, different gear ratios will make this more interesting.)